# How to build Android Bluetooth server app handling data sent from Raspberry Pi using pybluez

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, android-bluetooth, pybluez

I was wondering how to build Android app handling data sent from Raspberry pi.

I installed pybluez module on Raspberry Pi and send data using following python script.

```
import bluetooth
port = 1
sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )
sock.connect((targetBluetoothMacAddress, port)) 
                      #targetBluetoothMacAddress is my phone MacAddress
sock.send("hello!!")
sock.close()
```

On my phone I did see two devices paired successfully. But can not find a way to get data sent from Raspberry Pi. Is there a way to build an app handling data from sock.send()?

Comment: The Android documentation contains a good example on how to use bluetooth in an application: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to consult the Android Bluetooth APIs, but yes you can build an app pretty easily. First what you'll wanna do is get a reference to the [BluetoothDevice](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice) that represents the Raspberry Pi you wanna connect to. You can do this by calling [BluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter#startDiscovery()) or by directly asking the framework for a device with the MAC address of the Raspberry Pi by calling [BluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#getRemoteDevice(java.lang.String)).

Once you get have the device you'll wanna open [BluetoothSocket](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket) with the device. To do this call [createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(java.util.UUID)). The UUID argument will more thank likely "0001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB" if you're connecting to the Raspberry Pi using SPP. The create method will return to you a BluetoothSocket which you will need to call [connect()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html#connect()) on. **Note, connect is a blocking call and you will need to perform all this work in a worker thread to prevent locking up your UI.** If connect returns successfully you've successfully connected with the device. In order to achieve back and forth communication with the device, you'll need to get ahold to it's [Input](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html) and [Output](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/OutputStream.html) streams by calling the following two methods [getInputStream()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html#getInputStream()) and [getOutputStream()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html#getOutputStream()) on [BluetoothSocket](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket).

Once you have these two streams you can send byte data back and forth between the two devices. note that reading and writing from the steams are blocking operations so I recommend creating two separate threads for reading and writing data, passing in the streams and a Handler into the thread constructor so you can send back data back to the UI thread.